# Haskell I/O: Filtering empty lists in CSV data-set

Tags: list, haskell, filter, io

Once again I'm stuck with haskell. This time I'm supposed to filter a CSV-dataset, using IO which I'm struggling to understand. Any additional related information is appreciated.

The structure is predetermined, and to me it seems messy. Is this really how one should do it? (I still have to do it this way, so this is a little "on the side"-question).

```
getRawData' :: String -> IO [[String]]
getRawData' fn = do
    s <- readFile fn 
    return $ parseCSVsimple s 



getRawData :: String -> IO [[String]]
getRawData fn = do
    d <- getRawData' fn
    return (dropEmpty d)



dropEmpty [[String]] -> [[String]]
```

**DropEmpty - This is where I need help** For a "normal" list I would just filter it straightforward, but this IO and different functions calling each other has me confused.

Sorry for stupid questions, I've programmed for 8 months and had to use 6-7 languages since then. Any general information related to the question is very much appreciated as well.

EDIT; FOLLOW-UP:

Thanks to good answers I have improved my understanding and implemented the following code:

```
dropEmpty :: [[String]] -> [[String]]
dropEmpty = filter(not . null)
```

However, I still see empty lists in the list. Is this because I am checking if the whole list of lists is empty? How do I sepcify that I want to check the "internal" lists?

Comment: As soon as you've reached `dropEmpty` you're outside of IO and only need to concern yourself with pure Haskell. So, just filter it like a normal list.

Comment: Your dropEmpty function is correct. Keep in mind that Haskell's list are immutable so your dropEmpty input list isn't modified, you have to check the result of the function

Answer (score 1):

The do keyword is just a sugar syntax for monads

Monad are defined like this:

```
class Monad m where
  (>>=) :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
  return :: a -> m a
```

Your `getRawData` function is equivalent to

```
getRawData fn = getRawData' fn >>= \d -> return (dropEmpty d)
```

As you can see in the monad definition, the second argument of `>>=` is the inner type of the monad, in your case, it's `[[String]]`

So there is nothing wrong with your code, you can use your dropEmpty without worrying about IO

Comment: Thank you! I will be able to figure it out now

Answer (score 1):

```
getRawData :: String -> IO [[String]]
getRawData fn = do
  d <- getRawData' fn
  return (dropEmpty d)
```

`getRawData` and `return` are the monadic actions in this **do** block. All other expressions do not have the **IO** type.

In particular, the expression to the left of `<-`, namely **d**, has just the plain type `[[String]]`. All parameters, namely `fn :: String` and `(dropEmpty d) :: [[String]]`, are also not in **IO**.

So you can get non-monadic values (e.g. `d`) out of the monadic actions (e.g. `getRawData'`) easily. However, you can only do so temporarily: You cannot make `d` escape the **do** block, only `IO d`. This is a "core feature" of monads in general.

This is only a very superficial explanation to give you a quick start on monadic code. I recommend you read up on monads. Learn how monads are desugared. Take the `state` monad for example, and understand what problem it solves by trying to re-implement it.

Comment: Thanks alot :) I think I will be able to make sense out of this!